# What are these patterns showing up in bubbles in this bottle (link to video in description)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

[image]What are these patterns appearing in the little bubbles on the surface of the water here? The bottle is filled with boiling water.

(1:25 for shows the best example best example)

https://youtu.be/-HIX0f18Ymw

Comment: Questions on the site should be standalone and not depend on external links continuing to work.  Please put some text description of what is there and perhaps a screen capture of what you see, as there you can upload images to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but they could just be tiny bubbles of vapor that rise from the liquid and bunch together on because of the surface tension.

Many of the bubbles pop at the same time because of grazing air currents.